# lookupSession "_ID" throws error using Yesod / Haskell for authentication

Tags: templates, haskell, yesod

I have the following in my  `chat.hamlet` file, and want to show it whenever a user is logged in and we have a `maybeAuthId`.

```
<div style="float:left">
    $maybe _ <- maid
        <p>Your current auth ID: #{show maid}
        <h3>
            <a href=@{AuthR LogoutR}>Logout
    $nothing
        <h3>
            <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}>Register / Login
<br clear="all"/>
```

I tried to define `maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"` but got a type error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Key User’ with ‘Text’
    Expected type: HandlerT App IO (Maybe (AuthId App))
      Actual type: HandlerT App IO (Maybe Text)
    In the expression: lookupSession "_ID"
    In an equation for ‘maybeAuthId’: maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
instance YesodAuth App where
    type AuthId App = UserId

    loginDest _ = HomeR
    logoutDest _ = HomeR
    authPlugins _ = [ authBrowserId def
        , authGoogleEmail clientId clientSecret
        , authEmail
        ]

    -- Need to find the UserId for the given email address.
    -- Take it from database
    getAuthId creds = runDB $ do
        x <- insertBy $ User (credsIdent creds) Nothing Nothing False
        return $ Just $
            case x of
                Left (Entity userid _) -> userid -- newly added user
                Right userid -> userid -- existing user

    authHttpManager = httpManager

    maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It looks like perhaps you haven't turned on `OverloadedStrings`? I believe that yesod uses this feature very heavily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't be setting `maybeAuthId` at all. There's a [default one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.12/docs/src/Yesod-Auth.html#maybeAuthId) with a fair amount of extra logic to turn the returned `Text` into a proper `AuthId`:

```
-- | Retrieves user credentials from the session, if user is authenticated.
--
-- This function does /not/ confirm that the credentials are valid, see
-- 'maybeAuthIdRaw' for more information.
--
-- Since 1.1.2
defaultMaybeAuthId
    :: (YesodAuthPersist master, Typeable (AuthEntity master))
    => HandlerT master IO (Maybe (AuthId master))
defaultMaybeAuthId = runMaybeT $ do
    s   <- MaybeT $ lookupSession credsKey
    aid <- MaybeT $ return $ fromPathPiece s
    _   <- MaybeT $ cachedAuth aid
    return aid
```

If you don't set `maybeAuthId`then this default implementation will be used.

Comment: How would I get it into my hamlet file? I'd like to show it on my page.

Comment: @Spacemoose What you want to do is not to override `maybeAuthId` but instead to _use_ it, and do additional processing to turn the `AuthId` into  a piece of plain text containing the username, then use _that_ text in your template.

Comment: Well, do you have `maid` in scope at the point where you invoke the template? My impression is that should just work...?

Comment: I did this in my .hs : `maid <- defaultMaybeAuthId`. In my hamlet i did this: `<p>Your current auth ID: #{show maid}` and then i got this returned:

`Your current auth ID: Just (UserKey {unUserKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}})`

Comment: Looks like you need to use `getAuthEntity` to look up the actual user info in the db? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.12/docs/Yesod-Auth.html#t:YesodAuthPersist -- the `maybeAuth` function in the same file looks like it does it for you...

Comment: `maid <- lookupSession "_ID" ` gives me Just "1"

Comment: The suggestion is `maid <- maybeAuth`

Comment: I am getting `chat.hs:337:11:
    No instance for (Show User) arising from a use of ‘show’
    In the first argument of ‘toHtml’, namely ‘show maid’
    In the first argument of ‘asWidgetT . toWidget’, namely
      ‘toHtml (show maid)’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      (asWidgetT . toWidget) (toHtml (show maid))`

Comment: So, figure out what the User type is coming back from maybeAuth, and apply the appropriate function to it to extract the user id.

Comment: i get back `Just (UserKey {unUserKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 3}})` from `maybeAuthId`. I do not want the "3" though. Because that is the id.  I want the email.. How do i get it from my database?

Comment: I would also take the Id though. How do i get the "3" only? Instead of the `Just (UserKey {unUserKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 3}})`